# Physical degree of freedom and gauge fixing?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, higgs, degrees-of-freedom

I'm confused with the gauge fixing in the Higgs mechanism.

So if we have an action like 
$$S=\int |D\phi|-\frac{1}{4}F^2 -V(\phi) ~ ,\tag{1}$$
then expand around some non-trivial vacuum, then we have terms like 
$$\int \partial_\mu \phi\partial^\mu \phi -2 m A_\mu \partial^\mu \phi +m^2 A_\mu A^\mu +\dots ~,\tag{2}$$
which can be written as 
$$\int m^2(A_\mu -\frac{1}{m}\partial_\mu \phi)(A^\mu -\frac{1}{m}\partial^\mu \phi)+\dots ~.\tag{3}$$
Then since the original action (1) has a gauge symmetry $A\rightarrow A-\partial \alpha$ for any function $\alpha$, we can fix the gauge (by choosing some $\alpha$), in this case $\alpha=\frac{1}{m}\phi$. Then above actions looks like 
$$\int m^2 B_\mu B^\mu+\dots ~, $$
where $B\equiv A-\frac{1}{m}\partial \phi$. I think this is how Higgs mechanism works and essencially you are removing the "unphysical degree of freedom" (in this case $\phi$)

My question is what if we take $m=0$? Then Eq.(2) looks like 
$$\int \partial_\mu \phi\partial^\mu \phi -2 m A_\mu \partial^\mu \phi +\dots  ~.$$
So we can't rewrite the action in nice forms like Eq.(3). 
Then what kind of gauge should I choose to see the physical degree of freedom? 
I'm guessing I can't choose a gauge like $A\rightarrow A-\partial \alpha A$ where $\partial \alpha = A$.

Comment: What does your [standard summary](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Englert-Brout-Higgs-Guralnik-Hagen-Kibble_mechanism#Spontaneous_breaking_of_a_local_gauge_symmetry) say?

Comment: When $m=0$ then you don't have a Higgs particle. Also, why is there a $m$ in the last term in the last equation- there aren't $2$ different masses - the last term should vanishes too.

Comment: @CinaedSimson Very true. Sorry did't even notice. Thanks